Unable to Call Azure Function App from Synapse Analytics using Synapse's MSI
I want to call the Azure Function App method from Synapse Analytics notebook without using Function Keys/Admin Keys. The Synapse Analytics' MSI has 'Contributor' role in the Azure Function App.
Apart from this what setup do I need to perform at the Function App -> Authentication (Add Identity Provider) to call function app method from Synapse Analytics notebook.
After that I would like to know how the access token needs to be generated from Synapse notebook to call the function app method. (i.e. mssparkutils.credentials.getToken)
